# A dual Windows Service / GUI applicaton with Delphi

Tags: windows-services, delphi-6

Is a dual Windows Service / GUI applicaton possible with Delphi?

I mean, when its exeutable file is started normally, it appears as a normal GUI application that is used for something other than its Windows Service function. For example, a configurator for Windows Service.
Or, for example, in GUI mode it could be a database client with TDBGrid etc and in Sevice mode it starts its own HTTP server and acts as a web application. Both are sharing the same database access code.

I looked into `TServiceApplication.Run` and didn't understand how can I distinguish between normal start and start as a service.

Of course, I could put some command line switch branching around this construct:

```
if GuiModeSwitch then begin
  Forms.Application.Initialize;
  Forms.Application.CreateForm(TConfigForm, ConfigForm);
  Forms.Application.Run;
end
else begin
  SvcMgr.Application.Initialize;
  SvcMgr.Application.CreateForm(TMyService, MyService);
  SvcMgr.Application.Run;
end;
```

But I would like that the GUI mode is started when no command line parameters are specified.

Comment: It's perfectly possible. But I probably wouldn't do it. I wouldn't want my service executable stuffed full of VCL code. I'd put the shared code in a DLL and have two executables that use the DLL.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I am mainly asking with a goal of making a gradual transition to the web while still having a monolyte hard decompilable executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the **SvCom** component can help you in Delphi pascal window service setting up.

[Step 6. Use service application as a regular one](https://www.aldyn-software.com/examples/002-AdvancedService/6-run-service-application-as-a-regular-one.html)